# Can't access flask @login-required APIs in front-end

Tags: javascript, flask, http-headers, session-cookies

We have a server which is implemented by python flask and it's RESTful. Since it is RESTful, we must develop the front-end pages using APIs. 
The problem is, our server uses flask's built-in Login_manager and session modules to manage client sessions. When I try to send requests to @login-required APIs, the server won't allow me. Based on my searches, I have to somehow send front-end's session cookie to the server, along with my requests. So how should I do this (If this is the solution)? And what should I add to my javascript login and API fetch codes?

JS login :

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login';
  var user = {
    'email': email,
    'password': password
  };
  request.open('POST', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
      var resp = JSON.parse(this.response);
      if (resp.status === "OK") {
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(resp.user));
        document.cookie = "user_id="+resp.user.id;
        window.location.replace('app.html');
      } else {
        alert("User info not correct");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Request not made");
    }
  }
  request.send(JSON.stringify(user));
```

And then, script isn't working because the /showApps API is @login-required :

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/showApps';
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function(e) {
  //manage data

  }
  request.send();
```